# Group commutator relations and the neutral element.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, noncommutative-algebra

In Serge Lang: Algebra it is stated on page 69 that for a group $G$ that, if for $x,y,z\in G$ $y=[x,y]:=xyx^{-1}y^{-1}, z=[y,z], x=[z,x]$ is satisfied, we have $x=y=z=e$.
I see that $y=[x,y]$ directly implies $y=x^{-n}y^{2^n}x^n$ for $n>0$, but I need a hint why it is true for $n=0$.

Edit: As pointed out in the comments: the relation should be $y^n=x^{-1}y^{2^n}x$.

Comment: "but I need a hint why it is true for $n=0$" For $n = 0$, we get $x^{-0}y^{2^0}x^0 = y^1 = y$. Is that really what you were looking for? That doesn't seem to be very helpful, as it is true regardless of any commutator relations.

Comment: I cannot deduce that $y=x^{-n}y^{2^n}x^n$ for $n=0$.

Comment: I just deduced it for you in my previous comment. It's almost trivial. And I am not sure how it would help.

Comment: Ah, okay, you are right. I mixed it up with the relation $y^n=x^{-1}y^{2^n}x$, which also holds.